# How can I add a queried variable to my current query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I hope anyone could help me work this out.

Below is my table and code (which is a little wrong because of one thing..), let me put it part by part to further explain my situation..

Let's say I have this table for Pandimandata2002.dbo.tblCrew:

```
CaseNo    DatePIConsult    cgoInceptionDate
------    -------------    ----------------
TR12-A    12/03/2012       10/11/2012
TR13-S    11/15/2012       09/15/2012
PO09-B                     08/20/2012
SX58-Q    11/22/2012       11/01/2012
BR88-W    10/05/2012       11/05/2012
```

and I have this data for PostMeds.dbo.tblpms:

```
CaseNo    med_stat    med_stateff
------    --------    -----------
BR88-W    FIT         12/01/2012
TR12-A    UNDERTX     03/13/2013
TR13-S    UNDERTX     03/10/2013 
PO09-B    UNDERTX     01/25/2013
TR13-S    FIT         04/01/2013
BR88-W    UNDERTX     11/17/2012
```

From there, I would like to have this:

```
CaseNo    DIFF2
------    -----    
BR88-W    57         
TR12-A    122      
PO09-B    227     
TR13-S    137     
SX58-Q    133
```

- DIFF2 is the difference of two dates (say, DATE1-DATE2).

  DATE1 is equal to DATE NOW (4/4/2013) if CaseNo is not existing in PostMeds.dbo.tblpms

  DATE1 is equal to (max of med_stateff where med_stat is like '%FIT%') of a specific CaseNo

  OR ELSEIF max(med_stateff) is null or line is not existing, DATE1 will be equal also to DATE NOW (4/4/2013)

  DATE2 is equal to cgoInceptionDate if DatePIConsult is NULL

  ELSE DATE2 is equal to DatePIConsult

below is my current query:

```
SELECT
     t1.CaseNo,
     (SELECT
          CASE WHEN MAX(cast(o.med_stateff as datetime)) IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,
               CASE WHEN t1.DatePIConsult IS NULL THEN t1.cgoInceptionDate
               ELSE t1.DatePIConsult END, GETDATE()) 
          WHEN ----(select o.med_stat --------)
       DATEDIFF(DAY,
            CASE WHEN t1.DatePIConsult IS NULL THEN t1.cgoInceptionDate
            ELSE t1.DatePIConsult END,
       MAX(cast(o.med_stateff as datetime))) END AS DIFF2

       FROM PostMeds.dbo.tblpms o

       WHERE t1.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = o.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AS DIFF2

FROM Pandimandata2002.dbo.tblCrew t1
```

The wrong part of my code is in the condition for DIFF2..

In there, I would like to add the condition to get the value of med_stat where the value of med_stateff (w/c is aligned with med_stat) is the max value WHERE (or considering) CaseNo is equal to my particular SUBPRIMARYKEY. after I get that value, I have to check if that value is equal to some word ('FIT'), after that I can make the necessary adjustments for my code.

I really hope someone could help me sort this out.. thanks in advance to you guys..

Comment: How do you come up with 133 for SX58-Q?

Comment: ok.. ill edit my post and add it to the bottom

Comment: i added the explanation before the bottom part.. thanks @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've gathered your word problem into a query that at least gets the results you seem to be after. Well, it's still April 3rd for me, to get the results you wanted I used `SYSUTCDATETIME()`. You may want to change that to `SYSDATETIME()` depending on how far away you are from London.

```
SELECT CaseNo, DIFF2 = DATEDIFF(DAY, DATE2, DATE1)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    c.CaseNo,
    DATE1 = COALESCE(p.med_stateff, SYSUTCDATETIME()),
    DATE2 = COALESCE(c.DatePIConsult, c.cgoInceptionDate)
  FROM dbo.tblCrew AS c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT CaseNo, med_stateff = MAX(med_stateff)
      FROM dbo.tblpms 
      WHERE med_stat LIKE '%FIT%'
      GROUP BY CaseNo
  ) AS p
  ON c.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = p.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
) AS x;
```

Results:

```
CaseNo   DIFF2
------   -----
TR12-A   122
TR13-S   137
PO09-B   227
SX58-Q   133
BR88-W   57
```

You'll have to add the `ORDER BY` because I don't know how you got the order you show in the desired results.

Comment: ok.. im checking it.. thanks.. let me get back to you once i verified its correctness

Comment: Hi Aaron, there's something wrong.. i tried to add the DATE1 in my select statement and it only gets the date now (all '4/4/2013').. im using getdate()

Comment: Can't understand what you did or how it went wrong from a vague comment, sorry. See this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8807f/1) and change the query in the way you're trying to change the above, maybe I'll have some idea what you're trying to do and why you need to change it.

Comment: i tried to see what DATE1 is the code getting.. then I can see that they're all equal to date now.. but when i checked my data, some lines should get the DATE1 from p.med_stateff..

Comment: I don't think so. Again, this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8807f/2) shows that only some rows are getting `DATE1` from the current time. Also the query returns exactly the results you expected in the question.